Trouble Using Data Field in Vega Lite Code
I am using Vega Lite in a Power BI custom visual called the Deneb Visual. I have created ovals in my visual. I can of course color these ovals with static HEX codes. But when I try to instead use a dynamic data label, no color appears (the oval is brown in the picture bc that is the background visual color). It should be green based on the data that I am passing in.
Here is my code for the mark:
"mark": {
              //at the rim area
              "type": "line",
              "opacity": 0.6,
              "point": false,
              "interpolate": "linear-closed",
              "stroke": null
            },
            "encoding": {
              "x": {
                "field": "x",
                "type": "quantitative",
                "scale": {"domain": [-250, 250]},
                "axis": null
              },
              "y": {
                "field": "y",
                "type": "quantitative",
                "scale": {"domain": [0, 470]},
                "axis": null
              },
              "fill": {
                "field": "At_the_rim_perc",
                "type": "quantitative",
                "scale": null
              },   
            "order": {"field": "path", "type": "ordinal"}
            },

At_the_rim_perc is a Power BI text measure that dynamically change. When I use the same measure to dynamically color the background in the Power BI report itself, it works fine. It just seems that the Vega Lite code/deneb custom visual aren't interpretting it correctly. So it just shows no color.
Any thoughts?
enter image description here
I am simply looking for a way to dynamically change the colors of these ovals.

Can you supply a sample .pbix with data?

Hi, Sorry for the delayed response. And thanks for your willingness to take a look. Here is an example file. It's vega lite that maps out a basketball court. But the block in question is the mark that starts at line 64. I'm trying to dynamically control the color of the mark with a measure. But it the mark color just fills as blue and the hex code I'm trying to pass in is actually green.
https://1drv.ms/u/s!AuUIvLxzvO9P8kl7r3O_8KcR7elY?e=xOa7mZ

You need to set a scale of null if you're passing a value. There is an example on this page here: https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/scale.html#disable. Your spec is a bit confusing for me to debug now but this should put you on the right path.
